# display: none; on android

Tags: android, html, css

I have created a switchable list of "single image with text" and I only want the active to be visible. All works ok at PC browsers (tried Firefox, IE) but on mobile ANDROID browser (Chrome) I can only see the first "visible" image, while the rest keeps only displaying text.

html:

```
<ul class="tabs clearfix">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul><!-- tabs -->

<div class="box visible">
    <div class="box-text">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/pic1.png" width="437" height="545" alt="">
</div><!-- box -->

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-text">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/pic2.png" width="437" height="545" alt="">
</div><!-- box -->

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-text">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/pic3.png" width="437" height="545" alt="">
</div><!-- box -->
```

css:

```
.tabs li {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #cbcfd1;
    margin: 0 13px 13px 0;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    transition: background-color 0.15s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs li:hover {
    background-color: #8bcb9d;
}
.tab li.active {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #35a654;
}
.box {
    display: none;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.box.visible {
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

I understand from what I found here that there is some kind of problem with mobile Chrome but since I'm a beginner I can't make heads or tails of what I'm supposed to to with it to make it work. Can anyone help please? When I remove display: none; and put block in there, all images can be seen stacked below each other but that is not desired.

I found out that the problem only occures on a mobile phone size device. Galaxy Tab 2 tablet I tried displays everything ok.

Comment: first check if the image exist and are in the right directory. second investigate if you have media queries affecting your image display.

Comment: Thank you. The images are there. There are media queries affecting the images. It is a responsive web. But since I'm working from a template, I'm really not sure what is missing since even the template does the same thing. But thanks for the direction.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are having trouble with.  When I test the code given, the first box is displayed (as expected).

Comment: The problem is that when I switch to the other bullets, I'm not getting any image, only text. Each bullet is supposed to heave its own image. And it has - but only on PC browsers. Not on Android.

Comment: I found out that only the smartphone size device is affected by this. Tablet is ok. There must be something wrong with that @media for this resolution. I'm not skilled enough to work this out on my own.